# Django - change site_header when using `admin/login.html` template as a normal login template

Tags: python, django, templates

I am trying to use django's `admin/login.html` template as my login template for normal user.

Thing is it displays "Django administration" at the top of the log in form and I would like to change this.

I know it's possible to change this with a simple `admin.site.site_header = 'Log in'`.

The problem is: **this only works when browsing `/admin/login` and not `/login`**.

Here is what my `urls.conf` looks like

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views

from django.contrib import admin
admin.site.site_header = 'Log in'
admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^login/$', auth_views.login, {'template_name': 'admin/login.html'},
        name='login'),
    url(r'^logout/$', auth_views.logout, {'next_page': '/'}, name='logout'),
    url(r'^', include('qa.urls', app_name='qa', namespace='qa')),
]
```

When browsing `/login` I get the `Django administration` title and when browsing `/admin/login` I get the `Log in` title.

Is there a way to solve this without creating my own template?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need to pass a context variable with the name `site_header` into yours `urls.py` but that duplicates the whole thing:

```
url(
    r'^login/$',
    auth_views.login,
    {
        'template_name': 'admin/login.html',
        'extra_context': {'site_header': 'Log In'},
    },
    name='login'
)
```

Other possibility is to create [your own context processor](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/templates/api/#writing-your-own-context-processors) and fill `site_header` with whatever you want.

Another possibility is to copy `admin/base_site.html` into yours `templates` directory and overwrite the header.

Comment: I ended up using the last possibility you mentioned: copy/pasting (ugh, ugly) `admin/login.html` and overriding `{% block branding %}` with what I wanted!

Comment: It's not ugly but quite commonly used technique in Django :)